# Unable to identify source of exception error: Flutter

Tags: flutter

[Image of code that occurs with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDe7Z.png)

I am going through a udemy Flutter course and I do not understand why the try catch cannot handle the error with the if statement inside inside of the try{}. I have had this problem for this a couple of times and I have just avoided it by running error-free trials.

The code is as follows:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import '../models/http_exception.dart';

class Auth with ChangeNotifier {
  String _token;
  //tokens only last about an hour
  DateTime _expiryDate;
  String _userId;

  Future<void> _authenticate(
      String email, String password, String urlSegment) async {
    final url = 'UrlIsCorrectInMyCode'; //changed on purpose

    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        url,
        body: json.encode(
          {
            'email': email,
            'password': password,
            'returnSecureToken': true,
          },
        ),
      );
      final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      if(responseData['error'] != null){
        throw HttpException(responseData['error']['message']);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }

  Future<void> signUp(String email, String password) async {
    return _authenticate(email, password, 'signUp');
    //in order for the progress indicator to be shown
    //it must be returned so that it takes the future of
    //_authenticate and not just any future
  }

  Future<void> login(String email, String password) async {
    return _authenticate(email, password, 'signInWithPassword');
  }
}
```

And the class that registers UI and uses Auth:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../providers/auth.dart';
import '../models/http_exception.dart';

enum AuthMode { Signup, Login }

class AuthScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/auth';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    // final transformConfig = Matrix4.rotationZ(-8 * pi / 180);
    // transformConfig.translate(-10.0);
    return Scaffold(
      // resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [
                  Color.fromRGBO(215, 117, 255, 1).withOpacity(0.5),
                  Color.fromRGBO(255, 188, 117, 1).withOpacity(0.9),
                ],
                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                stops: [0, 1],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              height: deviceSize.height,
              width: deviceSize.width,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Flexible(
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 94.0),
                      transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(-8 * pi / 180)
                        ..translate(-10.0),
                      //transform allows to rotate or scale a box
                      //the '..' operator allows you to return the matrix4
                      //object that rotationZ provides instead of the void
                      //response that .translate provides
                      // ..translate(-10.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        color: Colors.deepOrange.shade900,
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            blurRadius: 8,
                            color: Colors.black26,
                            offset: Offset(0, 2),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        'MyShop',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color:
                              Theme.of(context).accentTextTheme.headline6.color,
                          fontSize: 50,
                          fontFamily: 'Anton',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    flex: deviceSize.width > 600 ? 2 : 1,
                    child: AuthCard(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AuthCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const AuthCard({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AuthCardState createState() => _AuthCardState();
}

class _AuthCardState extends State<AuthCard> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();
  AuthMode _authMode = AuthMode.Login;
  Map<String, String> _authData = {
    'email': '',
    'password': '',
  };
  var _isLoading = false;
  final _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  void _showErrorDialog(String message) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text("An error occured"),
        content: Text(message),
        actions: [
          FlatButton(
            child: Text("Okay"),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _submit() async {
    if (!_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      // Invalid!
      return;
    }
    _formKey.currentState.save();
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    try {
      if (_authMode == AuthMode.Login) {
        await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).login(
          _authData['email'],
          _authData['password'],
        );
      } else {
        await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).signUp(
          _authData['email'],
          _authData['password'],
        );
      }
    } on HttpException catch (error) {
      //this means a special type of error is thrown
      //this acts as a filter for the type of error
      var errorMessage = 'Authentication failed.';
      if (error.toString().contains("EMAIL_EXISTS")) {
        errorMessage = 'This email address is already in use';
      } else if (error.toString().contains('INVALID_EMAIL')) {
        errorMessage = 'This is not a valid email address.';
      } else if (error.toString().contains('WEAK_PASSWORD')) {
        errorMessage = 'This password is too weak.';
      } else if (error.toString().contains('EMAIL_NOT_FOUND')) {
        errorMessage = 'Could not find a user with that email.';
      } else if (error.toString().contains('INVALID_PASSWORD')) {
        errorMessage = 'Invalid password.';
      }
      _showErrorDialog(errorMessage);
    } catch (error) {
      const errorMessage = 'Could not authenticate. Please try again.';
      _showErrorDialog(errorMessage);
    }
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  void _switchAuthMode() {
    if (_authMode == AuthMode.Login) {
      setState(() {
        _authMode = AuthMode.Signup;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _authMode = AuthMode.Login;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Card(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      elevation: 8.0,
      child: Container(
        height: _authMode == AuthMode.Signup ? 320 : 260,
        constraints:
            BoxConstraints(minHeight: _authMode == AuthMode.Signup ? 320 : 260),
        width: deviceSize.width * 0.75,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'E-Mail'),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                      return 'Invalid email!';
                    } else {
                      return null;
                    }
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    _authData['email'] = value;
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                  obscureText: true,
                  controller: _passwordController,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 5) {
                      return 'Password is too short!';
                    } else {
                      return null;
                    }
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    _authData['password'] = value;
                  },
                ),
                if (_authMode == AuthMode.Signup)
                  TextFormField(
                    enabled: _authMode == AuthMode.Signup,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Confirm Password'),
                    obscureText: true,
                    //this allows stars to mask the input
                    validator: _authMode == AuthMode.Signup
                        ? (value) {
                            if (value != _passwordController.text) {
                              return 'Passwords do not match!';
                            } else {
                              return null;
                            }
                          }
                        : null,
                  ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                if (_isLoading)
                  CircularProgressIndicator()
                else
                  RaisedButton(
                    child:
                        Text(_authMode == AuthMode.Login ? 'LOGIN' : 'SIGN UP'),
                    onPressed: _submit,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                    ),
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 8.0),
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.button.color,
                  ),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text(
                      '${_authMode == AuthMode.Login ? 'SIGNUP' : 'LOGIN'} INSTEAD'),
                  onPressed: _switchAuthMode,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0, vertical: 4),
                  materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                  //reduces the amount of surface area that is tappable
                  textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share the code where the exception occurs.

Comment: it is always good to add code in text format, however after watching ss. you can not throw from catch block. which you are trying and becasue of that may be you are getting error.

Comment: @RajneeshChaurasia There is no code in the debug console and that is the only error that showed up. Is there any other way to access it?

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya The instructor kept saying that the throw was necessary to allow for catching errors in the non-provider classes. How else would i go about it?

Comment: are you sure it was in catch not in try bloc?

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya I just posted the code. Sorry I am very new to this! But I am pretty sure the throw error is in the catch statement

Comment: @JoshR Can you specify which line of code in the try block throws the error?. and why are you throwing the error in catch block?

Comment: add where you are using this code and try flutter clean because it is working fine for me.

Comment: @RajneeshChaurasia In the picture at the top it shows where the error comes however I do not get a specific message in the terminal

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya I tried clutter clean and I keep getting the error in the picture

Comment: try not to throw the error in the catch block because it is used to handle the error and return some appropriate message to the client. if you throw the error in the catch block then where will you catch the thrown error? So remove the throw statement in the catch block.then check if it works.

Comment: @RajneeshChaurasia If i remove the throw statement then the application no longer crashes. However, in the other file if it does not work then a message is supposed to pop up on the screen from the _showErrorDialog(errorMessage) method. Nothing appears on the screen (no AlertDialog) once the error occurs.

Comment: @JoshR you have to return some message that you want to be displayed from the catch block and then access that message to display on your app where you want .

Comment: @RajneeshChaurasia how would I go about sending that error over?

Comment: You can try paasing a callback to your login function and then call the callback when the catch block executes, then pass the error object to the callback where you can use the  error object to show popup in the AuthCard widget.

Comment: @RajneeshChaurasia When I changed 'throw error' to 'return Future.error(error);' the process worked correctly